# How to auto layout labels and textfields horizontally iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-autolayout

I have two textfields and labels in a row and I want them to stretch in proportion when orientation changes to landscape.

[image]

Here are the constraints

[image]
[image]

With current constraints I am getting following output

[image]

Notice how only the label was stretched.
I am not sure what additional changes are needed to the layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on label that you've selected in above shown image and drag the mouse pointer to the its superview you got op up smthg like below and select equal width.

[image]

When you done above step your component is streched to whole view so dont panic now select your component again and open size inspector. click on width constraint you got below screen

[image]

Now change the multiplier like this

[image]

Do same for all components and give multiplier as what width you wanted to set. It automatically works for you in all screens iPad and iPhone and all orientations.

Comment: thanks this was the quickest and easiest , less clumsy way :)

Comment: Welcome mate. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try following steps :

1. Give leading, trailing(to textfield), top and bottom constraint to label.
2. Give trailing(to textfield), top and bottom constraint to textField.
3. Give trailing(to second label), top and bottom constraint to second textField.
4. Give trailing(to view), top and bottom constraint to second label.
5. Select all field and give equal Width constraints to all view **OR** you can set horizontal hugging priority constant (249) for desired view which you want to grow according to screen width .

Comment: I definitely dont want equal widths , i m aware of that, can you tell me more about horizontal hugging ?

Comment: you need to horizontal hugging priority high to first label compared to textfield so that it width only grow width with orientation or screen width.

Comment: if you set this constraints according to steps then xcode gives error for correction use that.

Comment: if you want only first label width grow then set its horizonal hugging priority to 249 and for all other view 251;

Comment: I want all of them to stretch in proportion

Comment: all views are will growed but if you change priority to first label then its width grow  more according to screen width.

Comment: doesn't work still the first label grows others dont

Comment: then use another way give equal width to all and select first label's width constraint and set multiplier to first label(e.g 1.5) as per your needs

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can easily managed that With **Stack Views** .. 
It's quite easy to understand .. you just need to use **Horizontal Stack View**. it automatically adjust itself on orientation changed either by stretching or squeezing the content ..